I need to run multiple queries at one time
I have a Kusto Query where I need to check that the URL is enabled on ZScaler or not. I have more than 700 URLs to check. I need to run a single query which checks each URL at one time. Currently I am running a single query for a single URL.
CommonSecurityLog
| where DeviceVendor == "Zscaler"
| where DeviceEventCategory == "Global Allow"
| where DestinationHostName contains "amazonaws.com"
| summarize count() by RequestURL
| sort by count\_ desc

What do I need to change to run multiple URLs at one time? If I copy and paste all the aforementioned queries together with two different URLs (example is given below), it shows an error.

Please update your question with the code and error message that you mentioned. Thanks

What about querying everything with one query like this:
let urls = pack_array("url1", "url2", "...");
CommonSecurityLog
| where DeviceVendor == "Zscaler"
| where DeviceEventCategory == "Global Allow"
| where DestinationHostName contains "amazonaws.com"
| mv-apply word = urls on (
extend containsWord = DestinationHostName contains word
| summarize containsAny = max(containsWord)
)
| where containsAny == true
| summarize count() by RequestURL
| sort by count_ desc

Or use the in keyword where you need it.

I have multiple URLs'. Rest query will remain same only URL will be changed. Like in above query "amazonaws.com" and another query with different URL

I have changed my query. Check it out.

It shows an error.

Query could not be parsed at 'CommonSecurityLog' on line [1,73] Token: CommonSecurityLog Line: 1 Position: 73 Request id: 00740eb4-5325-49cb-9137-22f99c7cc5af

I´ve changed it. Semicolon was missing in the first line.

Is it working for you now? Could I helped you?
